# Add interior color and border style to buttons

Tags: button, border, settings, background-color

This is a snippet code of my Sub to insert a button via VBA (I simplified it removing parameters, dim...)

```
Sub MyInsertButton()
    Set t = ws.Range("G7")
    Set Btn = ws.Buttons.Add(850, 140, 150, 20)
    With Btn
        .name = "BtnG7"
        .OnAction = "Sub_CloseAll"
        .Caption = "Close all"
        .Font.Color = 157435
        .Font.Size = 10
        .Font.name = "Arial"
        .Visible = True
     End With                                                                                                                        
End Sub
```

I'd like to add some more details, but I'm unable to find the correct syntax for border, interior color etc,  can you help me, please?
These do not work and I get one 438 for each one:

```
.Borders.LineStyle = -4119
.Borders.Color = 12562000
.Borders.Weight = 4
.Interior.Color = 11892015
```

Thanks in advance

Michele